# Customizing buttons in Orbeon 4.5

Tags: orbeon

In proprties-local.xml I have defined persistence layer:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"
    value="MsSqlPersistance"/>

<property
    as="xs:anyURI"
    name="oxf.fr.persistence.MsSqlPersistance.uri"
    value="http://10.7.3.63:8080/MsSqlPersistenceLayerImpl"/>
```

So now, everytime I click on save or send button, there is HTTP PUT request sent to my **MsSqlPersistenceLayerImpl** REST service. 
Also there is

```
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.*.*"
          value="http://10.7.3.63:8080/orb_submit/orbSubmit"/>
<!-- HTTP method to use to navigate to the success page -->
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.method.*.*" value="post" replace="all"/>
```

As I understand, after clicking on *Send button* there is a HTTP PUT request send to my **MsSqlPersistenceLayerImpl** component and after success, there is another POST request send to **orb_submit** service.

Now, I would like after clicking *Send button* (workflow-send), not to send any HTTP PUT requests to my **MsSqlPersistenceLayerImpl** service, I want only to call (after form validation) `orb_submit` service. Is it possible?

---

**UPDATE**

Customizing buttons seems really hard for me. Normally, after clicking save my form is saved in database and the success message is shown - it's default behaviour. But when I put this code

```
 <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-draft.*.*">
    save
    then success-message("save-draft-success")
    recover error-message("database-error")
</property>
```

into `properties-local.xml` after clicking **save** nothing happens (no save, no message;I'd excepct still normal behaviour of course). Morover, trying to customize **workflow-send** in the same way, it has no affect at all. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline properties were not supported in 4.5. Try instead:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-draft.*.*"
    value='
        save
        then success-message("save-draft-success")
        recover error-message("database-error")'
/>
```